# Why am i getting an error on " 'X' identifier not found' "

Tags: c++, visual-c++

so i was trying to practice my gamehacking with c++ coding a basic triggerbot for CS:GO
everything went right, no errors until i tried to compile.

my code

Triggerbot.cc

```
#include "ProcMem.h"
#include "csgo.hpp" 
#include <ctime>
#include <chrono>
#include <iostream>
#include <Windows.h>
#include "triggerbot.h"


using namespace hazedumper;
using namespace signatures;
using namespace netvars;


ProcMem Memory;
DWORD ClientDLL;
DWORD localPlayer;

const DWORD teamOffset = 0xF4;
const DWORD hpOffset = 0x100;
const DWORD ELD = 0x10;

int mainProcess() {
    char process[9] = "csgo.exe";
    char module[20] = "client_panorama.dll";
    Memory.Process(process);
    ClientDLL = Memory.Module(module);
    localPlayer = Memory.Read<DWORD>(ClientDLL + dwLocalPlayer);

        while (true)
        {
            Shoot();
            Sleep(1);
        }

}

void Shoot()
{
    DWORD activeWeapon = Memory.Read<DWORD>(localPlayer + m_hActiveWeapon);
    DWORD entID = activeWeapon & 0xFFF;
    DWORD weapID = Memory.Read<DWORD>(ClientDLL + dwEntityList + (entID - 1) * 0x10);
    int myWeapID = Memory.Read<int>(weapID + m_iItemDefinitionIndex);
    bool scopedIn = Memory.Read<bool>(localPlayer + m_bIsScoped);
    int myTeam = Memory.Read<int>(localPlayer + teamOffset);
    int crossEnt = Memory.Read<int>(localPlayer + m_iCrosshairId);
    DWORD Entity = Memory.Read<DWORD>(ClientDLL + dwEntityList + (crossEnt - 1) * 0x10);
    int enemyHP = Memory.Read<int>(Entity + hpOffset);
    int enemyTeam = Memory.Read<int>(Entity + teamOffset);

    if (GetKeyState(VK_LMENU) && 0x8000 && enemyTeam != myTeam && enemyHP > 0);
    bool weapon = (myWeapID == 9) || (myWeapID == 40) || (myWeapID == 38) || (myWeapID == 11);

    if ((weapon && scopedIn) || !weapon) {
        Sleep(1);
        Memory.Write<int>(ClientDLL + dwForceAttack, 5);
        Sleep(18);
        Memory.Write<int>(ClientDLL + dwForceAttack, 4);
        Sleep(350);
    }


}
```

Error

```
Error   C3861   'Shoot': identifier not found
```

why is the identifier "Shoot" not found even though its declared below 
as

`void Shoot()`

Someone please tell me what im doing wrong.

Comment: I think you have to forward-declare shoot before `mainProcess()`.
Just add `void Shoot();` before `int mainProcess()`.

Comment: That would also be my guess. Would be interested to know if that works

Comment: I get these errors: https://prnt.sc/ps3p3t

Comment: @Hoekane Howcome you unaccepted ny answer? Both my answer and the other answer solves the problem in this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to forward-declare function `void Shoot()`. Compiler parses the file top down, and anything it hasn't seen yet, it doesn't know about.

Answer (score 0):

Move the `Shoot` function above `mainProcess`:

```
void Shoot() {
//...
}

int mainProcess() {
//...
}
```

Or forward declare `Shoot` above `mainProcess`:

```
void Shoot(); // forward declaration

int mainProcess() {
//...
}

void Shoot() {
//...
}
```

Also make sure that `ProcMem.cpp` is added as a source file to your project.